# Access Apache virtual hosts stored in /users directory

Tags: apache

I just upgraded my Mac to Yosemite and managed to get my development environment almost back to normal. In my old set up (which I didn't create), I stored all of my virtual hosts in /etc/apache2/users as separate `.conf` files.

I'm now no longer able to access those sites and I need to set up my virtual hosts in the /etc/apache2/extra in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. While it does work, I'd rather not have to do this as it's easier for me to organize all of these extra sites when they're in separate files.

Is there anything I can do to get it back to my original set up? Using my old httpd.conf file doesn't work and I've left the new file that originally came with the Yosemite installation because at the very least it left my development environment functional.

The contents of the `.conf` files I set up in /etc/apache2/users look like this

```
<directory "/Users/dev/Sites/*/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    #Require all granted
</directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/dev/Sites/mysitename"
    ServerName mysitename.dev
</virtualhost>
```

I was able to get my virtual hosts working by putting them all inside of the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. I only had to add the virtualhost bock and left the directory block and the `namevirtualhost *:80` line out as that was already inside of the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

Apache's Configuration file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` can include separate configuration files for processing through the [`Include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#include) and [`IncludeOptional`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#includeoptional) directive (the difference being, if `Include` doesn't get a matching file it will fail with error but `IncludeOptional` will just ignore it)

What you can do now is, add this line at the very bottom of your httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional users/*.conf
```

and place your separate configuration `.conf` files in `/etc/apache2/users` directory for including them in the main httpd.conf file